# How to repair lvm2 thin_pool?

Tags: lvm, proxmox, thinpool

Recently I had spun up a new vm that I was using as "tempstorage". Basically I set the size to 16tb which was the overall servers max space. I had 3 other vms up and running before this. Those vms all had 500GB and one 5TB. Neither of those were even close to that limit. Same with the "tempstorage" server. I got bout 1.8TB of data added before I woke up and the server was half running. The last drive was orange which means there is an issue with the drive. However shortly after rebooting the server my HPE server corrected the drive and it turned green. So I guess it was a result of running out of space.

Now I cannot get the lvm2 to start. The only message I get is "Manual repair required!" message. I have tried the:

```
lvconvert --repair pve/data
```

After running the above I once again get the "Manual repair required!" message and then when I check dmesg the only entry I see for thin_repair is:

```
[  638.183185] thin_repair[944]: segfault at 8 ip 00007fea094fb5be sp 00007ffedb8e5d18 error 4 in libstdc++.so.6.0.30[7fea094d5000+116000]
```

I still yield the same results with the message "Manual repair required!".

**fdisk -l**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1.36 TiB, 1499832039424 bytes, 2929359452 sectors
Disk model: LOGICAL VOLUME  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 1310720 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A3A2F44C-5D01-4566-9F1D-A0474AA28060

Device       Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2560       5119       2560   1.3M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     5120    1054719    1049600 512.5M EFI System
/dev/sda3  1054720 2929357454 2928302735   1.4T Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 16.37 TiB, 18003355459584 bytes, 35162803632 sectors
Disk model: LOGICAL VOLUME  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 1572864 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6B0CC303-8D66-4D65-90DE-196D9B7C90AA

Device       Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1       34        2047        2014 1007K BIOS boot
/dev/sdb2     2048     1050623     1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sdb3  1050624 35162803598 35161752975 16.4T Linux LVM

Disk /dev/loop0: 673.75 MiB, 706473984 bytes, 1379832 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

**pvs -a**

```
  PV         VG  Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sda2           ---      0       0
  /dev/sda3           ---      0       0
  /dev/sdb2           ---      0       0
  /dev/sdb3  pve lvm2 a--  16.37t <16.38g
```

**vgs -a**

```
VG  #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree

pve   1   9   0 wz--n- 16.37t <16.38g
```

**lvs -a**

```
LV              VG  Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert

  data            pve twi---tz-- <16.23t                                                  

  [data_tdata]    pve Twi------- <16.23t                                                  

  [data_tmeta]    pve ewi-------  15.81g                                                  

  [lvol0_pmspare] pve ewi-------  15.81g                                                  

  root            pve -wi-a-----  96.00g                                                  

  swap            pve -wi-a-----   8.00g                                                  

  vm-100-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz-- 500.00g data                                              

  vm-101-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--   5.00t data                                              

  vm-102-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz-- 500.00g data                                              

  vm-103-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--   5.00t data                                              

  vm-104-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz-- 100.00g data                                              

  vm-105-disk-0   pve Vwi---tz--  16.00t data
```

**pvscan**

```
PV /dev/sdb3   VG pve             lvm2 [16.37 TiB / <16.38 GiB free]

  Total: 1 [16.37 TiB] / in use: 1 [16.37 TiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

**lvscan**

```
inactive          '/dev/pve/data' [<16.23 TiB] inherit

  ACTIVE            '/dev/pve/swap' [8.00 GiB] inherit

  ACTIVE            '/dev/pve/root' [96.00 GiB] inherit

  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-100-disk-0' [500.00 GiB] inherit

  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-101-disk-0' [5.00 TiB] inherit

  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-102-disk-0' [500.00 GiB] inherit

  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-103-disk-0' [5.00 TiB] inherit

  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-104-disk-0' [100.00 GiB] inherit

  inactive          '/dev/pve/vm-105-disk-0' [16.00 TiB] inherit
```

**vgdisplay**

```
--- Volume group ---

  VG Name               pve

  System ID            

  Format                lvm2

  Metadata Areas        1

  Metadata Sequence No  31

  VG Access             read/write

  VG Status             resizable

  MAX LV                0

  Cur LV                9

  Open LV               0

  Max PV                0

  Cur PV                1

  Act PV                1

  VG Size               16.37 TiB

  PE Size               4.00 MiB

  Total PE              4292205

  Alloc PE / Size       4288013 / <16.36 TiB

  Free  PE / Size       4192 / <16.38 GiB

  VG UUID               FwXD4j-Y1q4-DyV0-i34b-qGSw-zwAO-2aHh2f
```

Comment: I have managed to fix this with the help of updated thin_repair tools. Check out: https://github.com/jthornber/thin-provisioning-tools